# How to create bootstrap designs with margin on both sides (preferably conditional)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a webpage using bootstrap. I am aiming to create the webpage with design like sites such as LinkedIn, Autocar of for that matter this website **where** there is a margin on both sides and it remains consistent throughout the website. What changes do I need to make in bootstrap to make this happen? Currently I have started with the starter-template provided by bootstrap. I just cannot create margins for the whole template or for that matter even the basic bootstrap navbar.

Secondly, if this margin width could be dynamically adjusted according to the resolution, that would be even better. While I did try media queries, none of them have worked so far. I do not get any error even in console, but I do not get the margins either,

**EDIT:** JS Fiddle for the same can be found at: https://jsfiddle.net/dpwr2ag1/

Approaches tried so far include use of media queries, changing padding and margins in navbar class of bootstrap, trying to change the width of the navbar.

I can make this work IF I wrap up all this in a HTML `<div>` with a desired width but that is a hack-ish approach I don't wish to take.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @Alorika The approaches I tried have not worked. I could get a center aligned div to work but that is a hack-ish approach

Comment: But still you need to share that approaches whatever you tried, so that the community members can help you better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In bootstrap you have 2 main classes for containers
container and container-fluid

Container adds margin and uses the grid system.
Container-fluid set the width to 100%

If you want to make conditional changes to the layout you should use media queries.

Some documentation you should read before proceeding:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

[EDIT]

sample code

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>My awesome page</title>
    <link href = "bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href = "custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class = "container">
        <h1>The title</h1>
        <p>The content</p>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>


custom.css: 
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
.container{
    width:100%!important;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: I am not planning to use grids. So if I set the container-fluid width to say 75%, will the whole website have a width of 75%? Sorry, I am not much experienced in this stuff

Comment: No problem...i think the best thing you can do is since you are not that experienced is just use the container class of bootstrap. it dynamicly changes the width of your. The grid system is not required by the way but with using the container class it sets fixed widths to the container. If you want to customize those you can use the media queries to do so

Comment: Hey, sorry I was busy with something else. I tried your suggestion on the starter-template. But It is not leaving margins on either side. The fiddles is at https://jsfiddle.net/dpwr2ag1/ Could you please take a look and help me with this?

Comment: @ashhem i made a small mistake but i updated the fiddle with working code :P The thing is you have to overwrite the bootstrap classes. You will see it in the fiddle. I added some colors for extra visual confirmation and some christmas vibes ^^ https://jsfiddle.net/dpwr2ag1/4/

Comment: This is great!! HOwever, I want margins on whole page on both sides right from the beginning. Even the navbar should not be end to end. Any tips?

Comment: Than you will need to wrap the nav bar in a div with class container so it scales with the page :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98208/discussion-between-ashhem-and-keyboard-ninja).

Answer (score 1):

That's the role of Media queries, and [Bootstrap media queries](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries) already gives you some examples. You can define ranges of widths where you want your margins to change. For example: to have a `1em` width in maximum screen width of `1024px`

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    div.container{
        margin-left: 1em;
        margin-right: 1em;
    }
}
```